# On image hover display text-div over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel-blade

Alright so I've been searching around for this question and found a lot of topics, but for some reason I cant manage to get the effect I want.

So I've got a slider with generated content, see code below.

```
@foreach ($elements['instagram-highlights']['subs'] as $item)

<img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

<div class="text-content">
     {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
</div>

@endforeach
```

The class text-content is set to display: none. When the img instagram-home-items is hovered the content of text-content should be placed on top of the image. For some reason, this won't work. The CSS i've got so far is below:

```
.text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;

}

.instagram-home-items:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It's probably very simple, but I can't seem to get it right. Thanks!

EDIT: The answer from Tripleb worked for the hover, now the next problem is the slideshow. I'm using Carousel2 but for some reason the slider stops working when I put a DIV in front of the image. Code being used now below:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" style="width:auto;"
 data-cycle-fx=carousel
 data-cycle-timeout=4000
 data-cycle-prev="> .cycle-prev"
 data-cycle-next="> .cycle-next"
 >

@foreach ($elements['instagram-highlights']['subs'] as $item)

    <div class="img_ct">
        <img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

        <div class="text-content">
            {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And the CSS that Tripleb provided:

```
    .text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;
}

.img_ct{
    position:relative;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}


.instagram-home-items{
    display:block;
}

.img_ct:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any suggestions on that part?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle with HTML / CSS

Comment: is it really necessary to provide a fiddle, since the whole code is there?

Comment: Please roll back the edit with the second question and create a new one for it. Also select the best answer for the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css selector is wrong you are selecting "parallel" the text is not a descendent of the image but a sibling

```
@foreach ($elements['instagram-highlights']['subs'] as $item)
<div class="img_ct">
    <img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

    <div class="text-content">
        {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

.text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;

}

.img_ct{
    position:relative;
}


.instagram-home-items{
    display:block;
}

.img_ct:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This does work as it should, but for some reason the slider has stopped working now. The hover is perfect. I'll edit the main question with your code and the code that provides the slideshow

Answer (score 1):

You CSS code assumes that the .text-content is a child of the .instagram-home-items. But in your HTML they are actually siblings. What you should do is wrap them in a container div like so:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
   <img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

   <div class="text-content">
       {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, change your css to this:

```
.item-wrapper:hover .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

.text-content isn't a child of .instagram-home-items

Try this:

```
@foreach ($elements['instagram-highlights']['subs'] as $item)
<div class="instagram-home-items-wrapper">
    <img class="instagram-home-items" src="{{ $item['instagram-items']['image'] }}">

    <div class="text-content">
     {!! $item['instagram-items']['textfield'] !!}
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And in your CSS

```
.text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
    color: #fff;
    display:none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s;

}

.instagram-home-items-wrapper:hover > .text-content {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.instagram-home-items:hover .text-content` that selector is looking for an element with the class `text-content` that is a child of an element with the class `instagram-home-items`. Since you can't nest element within an `img` tag, I'm sure this isn't what you're looking for.

Try using a sibling selector instead like this: `.instagram-home-items:hover + .text-content`.

Best of luck!